# Correct way to pass data in a php live turn based game

Tags: php

I'm going to code a university project in php which is an online turn based game, in one part of this project there is the ability to play live games.

My idea is storing the board's last condition in database and then the users would have a refresh of board every X seconds using AJAX and play their turn (If it's their turn), then the data would be sent to server using AJAX and if it's valid, the board condition will be updated in database and this circle will go on until the end of the game.

My guiding professor for the project insists that since it's a live game, the data should not be stored in database and it should be somehow in the memory of the server, by his example something "like SOCKET Programming" ...

Here are my questions:

What is the correct way to do what I'm about to do?

Is my guiding professor's idea reasonable?

Is there a logical way to not use database or file storing method in a php online website with my scenario? (If the answer is "Yes" please guide me to the correct Library or functions set)

Comment: This is just my opinion, but despite what your professor is saying, PHP is not meant for this.

Comment: Is PHP mandatory? If not, choose something else, ex nodeJs, PHP isn't a programming language for Game. NodeJs is extremely good according to your prof's hint (Socket programming)

Comment: Yes, php is mandatory, and why isn't php for games? There are a hell of online web based games written in php ...

Comment: @Night2 I guess what they've meant was that PHP is not made for live games that uses WebSockets (e.g) as a main resource for communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ReactPHP` for async programming with `PHP`. It brings almost the same functionality as `NodeJS`.

Don't use databases. You can keep values in PHP session, but I would strongly suggest using a KV storage such as `Redis` and keeping values in memory. That way, data won't be lost on webserver restart and you won't slow down application because of database hits.

Don't use longpolling if you don't want to make your professor laugh at you. If you can handle it, ReactPHP (+Restful backend) + Redis + AngularJS combo will be more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are conflating two separate issues. One is how you manage the game generated data (in memory or database); the second is how your app implements communication between the client and server (websockets, long polling, traditional polling).

One of the problems with using a database in your scenario, is that you may be storing a lot of data that does not really need to be persisted.  Since each move is written to the DB you may create more lock contention on the database than needed.  This could be a problem as your game scales.  Alternatively you could persist the data periodically or when the user decides to save the game.  For managing the state of the board on a move-by-move basis you could use a tool like memcache that runs in memory.

As others have noted PHP does not provide good support for websockets.  Long polling is another option.  However that will not scale well if you are using a traditional LAMP stack (apache's mod_php).  This is because mod_php is not thread-safe so Apache must use a process for every request ( the prefork multi-processing model).  Since long polling keeps requests open until a message needs to be pushed to the client, this may take up too many processes.  One alternative is to use PHP-FPM (http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) which is thread safe and allows you to optimize Apache using the Worker Multi-Processing Model that can handle multiple requests per thread. Traditional polling via ajax can put an undue load on the server if many requests return no new information.  But it may be your best option given the technology stack you are using.

Can you use a database? Yes.  But you'd be better managing the board state in memory.  Sockets programming is about communication, not storage or memory.  And its not really an option in PHP.  Your best bet is probably having the clients poll the server via ajax call.  Put some thought into the optimal poll interval for your game.  Choose the interval at which you are not wasting resources with calls that do not return new info, but are updating the board quickly enough to make for a good experience.

Comment: I don't need to store each move, only the last board condition will be enough which will be a 400 chars string in my case. So is your suggestion in a traditional LAMP like mine to update the board using repetitious AJAX calls, return info from server when data is changed and return empty when nothing is changed, but what about the game's board state? DB or Shared Memory? Isn't a DBMS managing data in memory and writing it to disk when needed itself?

Comment: I meant to say that you will be storing the board state after each move.  Correct me if that assumption is wrong.  The DBMS will write each insert/update command to disk.  So if you are storing the board state after each move, then each move will require a disk write.  Using memcache you can keep the board state in memory except when you actually want to save the state of the board beyond the current session.  And yes, I recommend using Ajax calls to poll the server for latest data at regular intervals.  You can return the current board state, and let the client update if anything has changed

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this in PHP, the top 2 easy solutions I can think of right off the bat:

1. Use a sender/receiver model, similar to what chat systems use. This is pretty efficient and only updates if there is data to be shown. There are many ways you can implement this via PHP. One way to implement this is via a listener.
2. Using a UDP/TCP sockets (each having their pros/cons) to send and receive the messages. In this structure there would be a daemon in the back that constructs the socket and each user playing would send/receive the info.

I am pretty sure there are many other ways to do this, but this is what I personally have used and can vouch for. Other things you can use is using memory storage like memcached or a more complex/robust messaging system like rabbitMq/zeroMq/etc.

Comment: So, both these solutions require you to run a separate (PHP) program on the back-end which persists between communications (i.e. PHP is not being run as a script by the web-browser)? I agree that's possible, but I'm not sure I would choose PHP if I were going to implement that.

Comment: @SpaceDog An alternative solution like I mentioned is to use memory storage like Memcached.

Comment: I agree that this could be done, but I don't think that PHP _without a persistent database_ is the correct tool for this job. If the server reboots you lose the state of all in-progress games. If he used a database for persistent storage _and_ memcached for memory access it may be a good choice but it sounds like a database cannot be used at all.

Comment: @Aziz Saleh: You have provided solutions but I still can't see which one is the logical and the best since you didn't provide any reasons for why we should use them, I still believe the database one which is my own idea is the best.

Comment: @vvanasten, I said the guiding professor my db solutions and he insisted on the memory way, but this doesn't mean that I can't use my way, I just need a reasonable answer to convince him that his way isn't right in this project scenario (If memory way isn't really right).

Answer (score 0):

In php you can't do that easily, i don't know the best solution either.

But using files can be a good way to go.

Try to use long polling (aka comet).

You should save the data of the battle (or whatever) in a file, then you can the when it was modified, if it has been modified then send the data, and restart the polling.

Here is an example:

> > Player 1 and Player 2 starts the battle.
> >
> > Both player starts a long poll.
> >
> > Watitng for Player 1 action
> >
> > Player 1 chose attack
> >
> > (Server handles the attack and save the new data of the battle to a file)
> >
> > Both players get the new data (because of the long poll)
> >
> > (Client handles the new data)
> >
> > Long polling restarts

Server side example for handling data change (PHP):

```
// We don't know how long this will run

$file = "battle.txt";

set_time_limit(0);

$timestamp = (isset($_GET["timestamp"]) ? $_GET["timestamp"] : null;



while (true) {
    clearstatcache(); // PHP caches the file data, such as modify time, clear this

    $lastchange = filemtime($file);

    if ($timestamp == null || $lastchange > $timestamp) {

        echo json_encode(file_get_contents($file));

        break;

    } else {

        sleep(1); // sleep for 1 sec to save CPU

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment, but the problem is that in this method we are still using a storage method like files or db, we could also save the last change date in db while in this one we will always have a running process/thread so if the concurrent playing users are a lot I guess Apache will crash or at least stop responding, right?

Comment: Well it depends, for a lots of player (+100k) you will probably need a very good server, but i don't know. (never had chance for an own large game)
If you want to store in memory you can check this:(looks good and interesting) http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php

But for the best result probably you will need a java or c server or whatever.

Comment: Ahhh forgot to mention NodeJS pretty good for things like this because of real time communication.
http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Thanks for helps, I will still wait to see if anyone can show me the correct way of doing this with reasons, you provided good solutions to work with memory and use comet. But I still need to know what is the right way for this scenario ...

Comment: You could have a look at non-persistent/in-memory solutions like memcached or Redis

Answer (score 0):

Your professor will expect you to do the task the way he sees it, because he wants to see if you [know/understand/able to do/can code] whatever he wants you to be able to code.

So, I am just guessing here:

1. You need a constantly running php script, which listens to the socket connection, processes the input, does some calculations with variables, returns some output back through the socket. You might create some interface that will start/stop this constantly running script using functions like exec() to operate with command line launching of the script and killing its process later - you might get bonus points for making such interface. All of the game data will be in the variables inside that constantly running script.
2. For every request from clients you would create a socket connection to that first constantly running script, pass data, get answer and return to display it to clients of your game.
3. You can use register_shutdown functions to permenently store current state of the game into some file or database, and then restore data from there when you run the constant script again. That way you still operate with everything in the memory, but you can shutdown the game temporarily and continue from where you left later. With that approach you need to create initialization function that will allow you to initialize game state from the saved data. I assume that you understand that game state contains all the current values, and also things like who is supposed to act next and etc.
4. You obviously need to handle every error. Display nice messages and etc.

If you get it all done - it will be a huge work, with creating and admin part of a website to control game server [start/stop game logic, load from saved states, user accounts and etc], the game interfaces for clients, with AJAX requests and etc, the background libraries with the code itself, probably OOP, if you need to show how you know OOP very well.

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, your professor probably would want you to do what he suggest you.

To twist it a little. How about making the server in PHP, make it listen to a socket, using PHP Sockets extension.

this way, you can show your professor, that you know about web sockets etc. and still complete your task using PHP.